# JS: llevo todo el día intentando

Tags: javascript

me gustaría que me ayudaran con un problema ya, tengo un código que me gustaría implementar a una función, llevo todo el día intentando, pero no comprendo como.

Estoy buscado añadir probabilidad no aleatoria, o se mejor dicho que haya una variante que establezca probabilidad.

Como veran en el codigo, es un "clicker game" algo muy sencillo de hacer, pero me gustaria agragar cada vez mas complejidad a este codigo llevandolo a un proyecto verdadero y aprendiendo de paso como funciona javascript.

El problema en si es que el botón "comprar" simplemente no funciona, no hace interacción de ningún tipo, y no entiendo el porque, errores no me lanza de ningún tipo, por lo que no detecto cual es mi error

Este es mi código

```
var punto = 0;

var inventario =[0,0,0];
var loot = ["Novice", "Squire", "Cleric"];
var probabilidad = [5,2,2];
var production = [1,1,1];

var precio = 100;

var constancia = 0;

function clic(){
  punto++;
}

function simulateEvent(chances){
    var sum = 0;
    chances.forEach(function(chance){
        sum+=chance;
    });
    var rand = Math.random();
    var chance = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<chances.length; i++){
        chance+=chances[i]/sum;
        if(rand<chance){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

function comprar(){
  if(punto >= precio){
    inventario[simulateEvent(probabilidad)]++;
    punto -= precio;
    precio++;
  }
  else{
    console.log("no have money")
  }

}

function producir(){
  for(contador=0; contador<inventario.length; contador++){
    punto += inventario[contador] * production[contador];
  }

}

function render(){
 document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = punto;
 document.getElementById("inventario").innerHTML =
  `Novice: ${inventario[0]}<br>
   Squire: ${inventario[1]}<br>
   Cleric: ${inventario[2]}`;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var FPS = 1;

setInterval(function(){
  producir();
},1000/FPS);

var FPS = 30;

setInterval(function(){
  render();
},1000/FPS);
```

[image: este es el código HTML que tengo para probar el código JS]

Y este es el código que quiero implementar a la función "comprar" para que me de un objeto de la variable loot con probabilidades ya hechas y sume 1 a su posición en el inventario.

```
function simulateEvent(chances) {
    var sum = 0;
    chances.forEach(function(chance) {
        sum+=chance;
    });
    var rand = Math.random();
    var chance = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<chances.length; i++) {
        chance+=chances[i]/sum;
        if(rand<chance) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var rewards = ["gold coin","silver coin","diamond","god sword"];
var likelihoods = [5,9,1,0];

console.log("You get a "+rewards[simulateEvent(likelihoods)]);
```

Comment: Hola Izumi, te recomiendo que te pases por el [tour] de bienvenida para conocer un poco más el sitio. EStaría bien que entendieras qué es un [mcve] y por qué no es buena idea añadir código como capturas de pantalla. Es **siempre** mejor copiar y pegar texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple vista veo que en la llamada a la función “comprar” en tu código HTML tienes puesto lo siguiente: onclick = “comprar;”. Prueba a cambiarlo por onclick = “comprar()”. 
Ahora mismo estoy desde el teléfono y no puedo verificarlo, pero echando un repaso por encima es lo que aprecio.
Ya me comentas qué tal.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, y pensar que el error esta en el código que no estaba viendo.